# JavaScript Create function to RETURN object from array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

This is for an assignment, I've worked on this for hours to no avail. Please DO NOT vote down - I was told that even the experts ask questions time to time:

I need to create a function to take in an array of arrays as n argument, and 'return' an object as shown at the end of my code below. (stackoverflow's filters make it awkward for me to ask a fluent question)

Function must use 'return' and NOT 'console.log'. Here's my code:

```js
var orders = [
    [
        ['first', 1], ['second', 2], ['third', 3], ['fourth', 4]
    ],
    [
        ['why', 'yes'], ['this', 'no'], ['if', 'so'], ['tit', 'tat']
    ]
];

function arrayToObject(array) {
  obj = {};
  for (var i= 0; i< array.length; i++){
    for (var j= 0; j< array[i].length; j++){
      obj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
    }
    return obj;
  } 
}
arrayToObject(orders);
//This function returns:
//{first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}

//However I need it to return this array:
//[{first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}
//{why: 'yes', this: 'no', if: 'so, tit: 'tat'}]
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: you cannot return something like this... it must be in the same object or array... Please fix your example of need output, so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the output that you need. This converts each array element to an object, then returns an array of the objects created.

```
var orders = [
    [
        ['first', 1], ['second', 2], ['third', 3], ['fourth', 4]
    ],
    [
        ['why', 'yes'], ['this', 'no'], ['if', 'so'], ['tit', 'tat']
    ]
];

function arrayToObject(array) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i= 0; i< array.length; i++){
    var obj = {};//obj holds the object that the next element in the array is converted to.
    for (var j= 0; j< array[i].length; j++){
      obj[array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
    }
    result.push(obj); //add obj to a result once we converted all elements of array[i]
  } 
  return result; //what is returned needs to be out of the for loop
}
arrayToObject(orders);

//output:  
//[ { first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4 },
  { why: 'yes', this: 'no', if: 'so', tit: 'tat' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement should be below the for statements, not inside. Your code is exiting the function before it gets the the second array.

```
function arrayToObject(array) {
  obj = [];
  for (var i= 0; i< array.length; i++){
    obj[i] = {};
    for (var j= 0; j< array[i].length; j++){
      obj[i][array[i][j][0]] = array[i][j][1];
    }
  } 
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: This format returns one single object with all items from the array in it. While they're paired correctly, I need to have each array within the array form its own object.

Comment: this is not possible like so.

Comment: Why not? Do you want to return an array of objects instead?

Comment: yes, my apologies. Yes, it was supposed to return an array of objects. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: I moved the objects into an array.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that... I've converted your code to EcmaScript6 and also moved return statement after the first loop. To return everything in once, I converted obj to an array and push each object in it separately.

```
var orders = [
  [
    ['first', 1], ['second', 2], ['third', 3], ['fourth', 4]
  ],
  [
    ['why', 'yes'], ['this', 'no'], ['if', 'so'], ['tit', 'tat']
  ]
];

function arrayToObject(array) {
  let obj = [];
  for (let current_list of array){
    let _tmpObj = {};
    for (let values of current_list){
      _tmpObj[values[0]] = values[1];
    }
    obj.push(_tmpObj);
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(arrayToObject(orders));
```

It's output:

```
[
    { first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4 },
    { why: 'yes', this: 'no', if: 'so', tit: 'tat' }
]
```